# Which function can approximated with Neural Networks using only linear activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks

I want to find out which functions can be approximated up to arbitrary accuracy using Neural Networks with only linear activations. On this [page](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0) I found out that with linear activation functions, the error in the prediction stays constant and is not depending on $x$. This means probably it has a bad accuracy, but I have not found out, if there is something like a URT for linear functions.

What I don't understand yet, how to relate the activation function to the actual model I want to predict.

My idea is that with only linear activation functions you can approximate only linear functions up to arbitrary accuracy. I would argue that the cost function:

\begin{align*}
C(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{w})&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-\hat{y}\left(\mathbf{x}_{i} ; \mathbf{w}\right)\right)^{2}\\ &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-\mathbf{w}\cdot \mathbf{x}_i - b_i\right)^{2}
\end{align*}

contains only a sum of linear functions, which cannot approximate a quadratic function for example. Maybe someone can help me writing that in a more rigorous way.

Comment: With linear activation function your output will always be linear because inputs are repeatedly multiplied with weights and added. Has nothing to do with loss function.

Comment: This is true, but don't answers my question, which functions can be approximated and how one can show this (maybe I didn't made that point clear).

Comment: yes in general you can only approximate linear functions this way -- but an NN can learn to exploit floating point quantization errors and learn nonlinear functions even with only "linear" activations! -- although i suspect this isn't what you're looking for

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325776/does-the-universal-approximation-theorem-for-neural-networks-hold-for-any-activa

Comment: @shimao ok that's interesting. Have you got a script/paper where I find a simple, but rigorous proof for that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of one or more linear functions is itself a linear function. A neural network using only linear activations can be rewritten as a linear function. [What is the purpose of a neural network activation function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228296/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-neural-network-activation-function/236386#236386)

Using a linear function, you'll be able to approximate functions which are single, straight lines, i.e. linear functions. Approximating a nonlinear function with a linear function will have some amount of error -- perhaps small enough to be ignored, perhaps too large to be acceptable. This judgement depends on what you need from your model.